# Back face culling for linestrips

Tags: opengl, directx, shader, linear-algebra

I have circle in 3D space (red on image) with normals (white)

[image: circle with normals]

This circle is being drawn as linestrip.

**Problem is:** i need to draw only those pixels whose normals directed into camera (angle between normal and camera vector is < 90) using discard in fragment shader code. Like backface culling but for lines.

[image: red is visible part of circle]

Red part of circle is what i need to draw and black is what i need to discard in fragment shader.

**Good example** is 3DS Max rotation gizmo, back sides of lines are hidden:

[image: 3ds max rotation gizmo]

**So,** in fragment shader i have:

```
if(condition)
    discard;
```

Help me to come up with this condition. Considering both orthographic and perspective cameras would be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you already described your condition:

> (angle between normal and camera vector is < 90)

You have to forward your normals to the fragment shader (don't forget to re-normalize it in the FS, the interpolation will change the length). And you need the viewing vector (in the same space than your normals, so you might transform normal to eye space, or use world space, or even transform the view direction/camera location into object space). Since the condition `angle(N,V) >= 90 (degrees)` is the same as `cos(angle(N,V)) <= 0` (assuming normalized vectors), you can simply use the dot product:

```
if (dot(N,V) <= 0)
    discard;
```

**UPDATE:**

As you pointed out in the comments, you have the "classical" GL matrices available. So it makes sense to do this transformation in *eye space*. In the vertex shader, you put

```
in vec4 vertex;  // object space position
in vec3 normal;  // object space normal direction
out vec3 normal_eyespace;
out vec3 vertex_eyespace;

uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelView;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    normal_eyespace = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);
    vec4 v = modelViewMatrix * vertex;
    vertex_eyespace = v.xyz;
    gl_Position=projectionMatrix * v;
}
```

and in the fragment shader, you can simply do

```
in vec3 normal_eyespace;
in vec3 vertex_eyespace;

void main()
{
    if (dot(normalize(normal_eyespace), normalize(-vertex_eyespace)) <= 0)
        discard;
    // ...
}
```

Note: this code assumes modern GLSL with `in`/`out` instead of `attribute`/`varying` qualifiers. I also assume no builtin attributes. But that code should be easily adaptable to older GL.

Comment: yes, that's what i wanted, but i'm stuck in calculation of this V and N vectors in correct space. can you please provide me sample code how do i get N and V vectors (i have normalMatrix, modelViewMatrix, modelViewProjectionMatrix, normal and vertexCoord on VS input)